# Defining a continuous function from a closed set

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $F\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a nonempty closed set and define $g(x) = inf\{\lvert x-a \rvert : a \in F\}$. Show that $g$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and $g(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \notin F$.

I wasn't sure how to start this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Incidentally, a good follow-up problem is to show that $g(x) \cdot \chi_{\mathbb Q},$ where $\chi_{\mathbb Q}$ is the characteristic function of the rationals, is discontinuous at each point in $F$ and continuous at each point not in $F.$ (As before, $F$ is any nonempty closed set.)

Comment: $x\notin F\rightarrow x$ not a limit point of $F \rightarrow \exists N_{e_{0}}(x)\subseteq F^{c}\rightarrow \forall a\in F,|x-a|\geq \epsilon_{0}\rightarrow g(x)\geq\epsilon_0\rightarrow g(x)\neq 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

1. Show $|g(x)-g(y)|\le |x-y|$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ by using the definition of $\inf$.

Fix $x,y$, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $z\in F$ , $|x-z|<g(x)+\epsilon$. Then
$$g(y)\le |y-z|\le |x-z|+|x-y|<g(x)+\epsilon.$$ Can you proceed from here?

2. Let $g(x)=0$ if $x\not \in F$, suppose $g(x)=0$ then there exists $x_n\in F$, $x_n\to x$. Use closedness of $F$.

Answer (score 2):

If $g(x)=0$, then, there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $F$ such that $|x-x_n|\to0$, so, $x_n\to x$. As $F$ is closed, this implies $x\in F$.

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$,(or $\mathbb{R}^n$, or even any other metric space in general), then, $$g(x)=inf\{|x-a|:a\in F\}\le inf\{|x-y|+|y-a|:a\in F\}=|x-y|+g(y)$$
By the analogous inequaility, $|g(x)-g(y)|\le|x-y|$. So, $|g(x)-g(y)|\to0$ as $|x-y|\to0$. Thus, $g$ is continuous.